# ¿ Cómo crear un trigger en MySql para descontar el stock?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo las tablas libros y detalleventas. Los campos de cada tabla son:

tabla **libros** (IdLibro, cantidad).

tabla **detalleventas** (IdVenta, IdLibro, Cantidad).

Cada vez que el usuario compra el producto, en detalleventas se guarda el IdLibro y la cantidad comprada de ese libro. Entonces quiero hacer un trigger para que después de hacer el `INSERT` en detalleventas, se descuente la cantidad en la tabla Libros.
No se bien como tengo que hacerlo, tengo este código hecho, que ademas marca un error en la palabra TRIGGER.

```html
CREATE TRIGGER tr_subtractBookStock
AFTER INSERT ON detalleventas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE libros
SET libros.cantidad = libros.cantidad - detalleventas.Cantidad;
WHERE libros.IdLibro = detalleventas.IdLibro; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el código que estás buscando:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_subtractBookStock
AFTER INSERT ON detalleventas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE libros
  SET cantidad = cantidad - new.Cantidad
  WHERE IdLibro = new.IdLibro; 
END;
```

Con respecto al tuyo verás que te faltan los `new.` y te sobra un `;` antes del `WHERE`. Tampoco es necesario que identifiques las tablas, pues no hay ambigüedad.

Aporto el dataset de pruebas por si alguien más quiere hacer reproducirlo:

```
CREATE TABLE libros(
  IdLibro int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cantidad int
  );
CREATE TABLE detalleventas(
  IdVenta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  IdLibro int,
  Cantidad int,
  FOREIGN KEY(IdLibro) REFERENCES libros(IdLibro)
  );
INSERT INTO libros (cantidad) VALUES (10),(15),(20);
```

Y la inserción que podría ejecutarse tras crear el disparador para probarlo:

```
INSERT INTO detalleventas (IdLibro, Cantidad) VALUES
  (1,2);
```

Comment: ¿Dónde lo estás probando? ¿phpMyAdmin?

Comment: no, desde MySQL Workbench.

Comment: ¿Has probado con el DELIMITER por si son los `;`? Pruébalo en phpMyAdmin a ver qué tal. A mí, desde dBForge, me funciona correctamente

Comment: Marca un error en new.IdLibro; (Statement is incomplet, expecting ';').y otro error  END;(is not valid at this position expecting EOF BEGGIN .........)

Comment: No te tortures, pruébalo desde el phpMyAdmin, puedes ser cualquier cuestión en la configuración de tu cliente MySQL

Comment: Gracias @David JP! tu trigger funciona!, solo que en Workbench tuve que quitarle BEGIN y END para que no me marque error de sintaxis

Comment: Claro, como sólo tiene una instrucción... ¡buena idea! [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO! Para que Workbench 8.0 no tire error de sintaxis, tuve que quitar BEGIN y END quedando de la siguiente forma:

```html
CREATE TRIGGER tr_subtractBookStock
AFTER INSERT ON detalleventas
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE libros
SET cantidad = cantidad - new.Cantidad
WHERE IdLibro = new.IdLibro;
```